# Database not updating in Flask restless though i am getting status 200 Ok in response

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-restful

This is the example that creates:

```py
import datetime
import hg_database as database
from geoalchemy2.types import Geometry

class messwerte(database.SerializableModel, database.db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "messwerte"
    id = database.db.Column(database.db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    messstelle = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    probe_datum = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    probe_uhrzeit = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    sammeldauer = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    labor_interne_id = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    labor_id = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    lagertemp = database.db.Column(database.db.Integer)
    extraktion_datum = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    virentiter = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    virentiter_streubreite = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    niederschlagsmenge = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    temperatur = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    cod = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    ammonium = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    populationsindikator_1 = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    populationsindikator_2 = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
    anzahl_der_krankheitsfaelle = database.db.Column(database.db.String)
```

Main File which is not writing to database:

```py
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from app import app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
import sqlalchemy 
import re
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = ""
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

def patch_single_postprocessor(result=None, **kw):
    '''Accepts a single argument, `result`, which is the dictionary
    representation of the requested instance of the model.

    '''
    print("result : {}".format(result))

    pass

def createRestFullBackend( classDefinition, apimanager, auth_func,
                           methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'],
                           url_prefix='/tables'):
    print("methods :: {}".format(methods))
    print("auth_func :: {}".format(auth_func))
    print("classDefinition :: {}".format(classDefinition))
    print("API manager :: {}".format(apimanager))
    restClassHandler = apimanager.create_api(
        classDefinition,
        max_results_per_page=None,
        methods=methods, url_prefix=url_prefix,
        # preprocessors=dict(GET_SINGLE=[auth_func], GET_MANY [auth_func]),
        postprocessors={
            'PUT_SINGLE': [patch_single_postprocessor]
        }, 
        )

    print("restClassHandler :: {}".format(restClassHandler))
    **Here I have used PUT but somehow its not working**
    return restClassHandler

class SerializableModel(object):
   def as_dict(self):
       return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}

   @classmethod
   def createRestBackend(cls,apimanager, auth_func):
        #from modules.helpers import createRestFullBackend
        createRestFullBackend(cls,apimanager, auth_func)
        print("created RestFULL backend for ", cls)


class HG_Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timeseriesstr = 'timeseries'
        self.timeseriesstrlen = len(self.timeseriesstr)
        self.timeseriesidlen = 4
        self.meta = MetaData()
        self.db = db
        filehandle = open('/serverapps/var/runconfig','r')
        self.POSTGRES_SERVER = ''
        self.POSTGRES_PORT = ''
        self.POSTGRES_DB = ''
        self.POSTGRES_USER = ''
        self.POSTGRES_PASS = ''
        for line in filehandle:
            line=line.strip()
            linelist=line.split('=')
            if linelist[0]=='POSTGRES_SERVER':
                self.POSTGRES_SERVER = linelist[1]
            if linelist[0]=='POSTGRES_PORT':
                self.POSTGRES_PORT = linelist[1]
            if linelist[0]=='POSTGRES_DB':
                self.POSTGRES_DB = linelist[1]
            if linelist[0]=='POSTGRES_USER':
                self.POSTGRES_USER = linelist[1]
            if linelist[0]=='POSTGRES_PASS':
                self.POSTGRES_PASS = linelist[1]
        filehandle.close()

    def opendb(self):
        uri='postgresql://'+self.POSTGRES_USER+':'+self.POSTGRES_PASS+'@'+self.POSTGRES_SERVER+':'+self.POSTGRES_PORT+'/'+self.POSTGRES_DB
        app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = uri
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False


    def getAllTables(self):
        self.meta.reflect(db.engine)
        return self.meta.tables.keys()

    def getTables(self, schema="public"):
        meta = MetaData(schema=schema)
        meta.reflect(db.engine)
        list = meta.tables.keys()
        regex = re.compile(r'timeseries\d\d\d\d')
        filtered = [i for i in list if not regex.search(i)]
        return filtered

    def getFieldNames(self, tablename):
        tableObject = self.openSATable(tablename)
        names=[]
        for i in tableObject.c:
            names.append(i.name)
        return names

    def getFieldTypes(self, tablename):
        tableObject = self.openSATable(tablename)
        return tableObject.c

    def getFields(self, tablename):
        tableObject = self.openSATable(tablename)
        return tableObject.c

    def getSchemas(self):
        insp = sqlalchemy.inspect(db.engine)
        db_list = insp.get_schema_names()
        return db_list

    def getTimeseries(self):
        self.meta.reflect(db.engine)
        list = self.meta.tables.keys()
        regex = re.compile(r'timeseries\d\d\d\d')
        filtered = [i for i in list if regex.search(i)]
        return filtered

    def openSATable(self, tablename):
        if '.' in tablename:
            l=tablename.split('.')
            tablename=l[1]
            schema=l[0]
        else:
            schema="public"
        return sqlalchemy.Table(tablename, self.meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=self.db.engine, schema=schema)

    def sql(self, cmd):
        return db.engine.execute(cmd)

    def createAttachmentTable(self, fortable):
        table = Table(fortable+'_attachments', self.meta,
                      Column('id', db.INT, primary_key=True),
                      Column('parentid', db.INT),
                      Column('attachment_table', db.String),
                      Column('attachment_id', db.INT),
                      Column('type', db.INT),
                      Column('name', db.String))
        table.create(db.engine)

    def dbTypeToLayType(self, typestr, name=""):
        if(typestr.startswith("VARCHAR")):
            return "string"
        if(typestr.startswith("CHAR")):
            return "string"
        if(typestr.startswith("DOUBLE PRECISION")):
```

```
 - return "float" if(typestr == "INTEGER"): return "int" if(typestr ==
   "BIGINT"): return "long" if(typestr == "BYTEA"): return "bin"
   if(typestr == "BOOLEAN"): return "bool" print("Warning: In "+name+"
   unknown type: "+typestr) return "string"
```

Response i am getting is showing that it has inserted the value in the database field but when i get the same instance it Never gets updated in the real database.

Response after doing PATCH request:

```
Response {
  "ammonium": "1",
  "anzahl_der_gemeldeten_krankheitsfaelle": "1",
  "cod": "1",
  "extraktion_datum": "1",
  "id": 2,
  "labor_id": "1",
  "labor_interne_id": "1",
  "lagertemp": "1",
  "messstelle": "abc",
  "niederschlagsmenge": "1",
  "populationsindikator_1": "1",
  "populationsindikator_2": "1",
  "probe_datum": "2020-07-29",
  "probe_uhrzeit": "12:48:10",
  "sammeldauer": "30",
  "temperatur": 2,
  "virentiter": "1",
  "virentiter_streubreite": "1"
}
```

But When I use Get request on the same instance:

```
{
  "ammonium": null,
  "anzahl_der_gemeldeten_krankheitsfaelle": null,
  "cod": null,
  "extraktion_datum": null,
  "id": 2,
  "labor_id": null,
  "labor_interne_id": null,
  "lagertemp": null,
  "messstelle": "abc",
  "niederschlagsmenge": null,
  "populationsindikator_1": null,
  "populationsindikator_2": null,
  "probe_datum": "2020-07-29",
  "probe_uhrzeit": "12:48:10",
  "sammeldauer": "30",
  "temperatur": null,
  "virentiter": null,
  "virentiter_streubreite": null
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note that a good Stack Overflow question focuses on a specific, isolated problem, with only the [shortest minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that lets others test the issue and determine whether it's resolved. I can see that you put real effort in your question. However, posts with a lot of code are often overlooked. Short and precise questions are more likely to get answered (and upvoted). I could not figure out where you write to the database.

Comment: I haven't gone through all that code, but the issue you describe usually happens when the transaction is not committed before you close the connection. While you are in the session you see the data, but other sessions cannot nor you once the session is closed.  Go over your code and check to see whether you ```COMMIT```. You can also tail the Postgres log to see what is going on.

Comment: @above_c_level restClassHandler = apimanager.create_api(
        classDefinition,
        max_results_per_page=None,
        methods=methods, url_prefix=url_prefix,
        )

According to https://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask.ext.restless.APIManager.create_api  Flask restless Documentation this should write to the database automatically